# bailiwick rules clarification on the AUTHORITY and ADDITIONAL section

Tags: domain-name-system

Here is an example of bailiwick rules I do not understand:

Resolving `adobe.net` from a `net.` TLD server gives:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
adobe.net.  172800  IN  NS  ns1.omtrdc.net.
adobe.net.  172800  IN  NS  ns2.omtrdc.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.omtrdc.net. 172800  IN  A   66.235.157.6
ns2.omtrdc.net. 172800  IN  A   66.235.157.7
```

And resolving `ns1.omtrdc.net.` gives:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
omtrdc.net. 172800  IN  NS  ns201.adobe.net.
omtrdc.net. 172800  IN  NS  ns202.adobe.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns201.adobe.net.    172800  IN  A   204.74.108.252
ns202.adobe.net.    172800  IN  A   204.74.109.252
```

If ADDITIONAL section is not trusted in both cases, it leads to a loop.

As I understood bailiwick, there are two rules:

- ADDITIONAL should not be trusted if they do not match the NS records from AUTHORITY section to avoid obvious compromise records send by the name server.
- AUTHORITY section NS should be a subset of the requested domain. `ns1.omtrdc.net.` is not a subset of `adobe.net.`, so the IPs in the ADDITIONAL section cannot be trusted.

However, I have seen some implementation where they are trusted because `ns1.omtrdc.net.` is a subset of `.net` (the TLD server that replied).

If I understand well (after reading some papers and implementations), since the TLD server manages the `net.` zone, we can believe anything under `net.`, i.e. the IP of `ns1.omtrdc.net.` that is the NS of `adobe.net`.

Does it make sense or did I forget some important parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to really see your question.

`ADDITIONAL` is defined as optional (so the client is free to ignore that data and for security reasons it should indeed ignore it most of the time)... except when there is no other way to achieve something, which are glues.
But the problem is that ADDITIONAL aka glues are not covered by DNSSEC, hence not authenticated, so have to be handled with care.

Note that your case of `adobe.net` using nameservers under `omtrdc.net` is not the definition of "in-bailiwick". It would have been in-bailiwick if nameservers name were also under `adobe.net`. So your case is just what is called "internal nameservers" as the nameservers names are internal to the same registry as the domain name they are authoritative on.

[ side personal note to be honest: I feel this setup of domain A using nameservers under domain B whose nameservers are back under domain A to be really dangerous. Any error in A **or** B possibly disables resolution of both A **and** B; this is some kind of loops, and loops in the DNS should be avoided (or treated with care and appropriate mitigations and safeguards) ].

You can find a lot of great definitions in RFC 8499 about DNS terminology.

It has this for example:

> Bailiwick:  "In-bailiwick" is a modifier to describe a name server
> whose name is either a subdomain of or (rarely) the same as the
> origin of the zone that contains the delegation to the name
> server.

As for

> Does it make sense or did I forget some important parts?
> You do great by showing DNS outputs of dig or similar but what is missing/vague is which nameserver you query for data, you should show that and study that to have a clear picture. In most cases of misunderstanding in the DNS I see it comes from a confusion between authoritative and recursive nameservers.

`ADDITIONAL` section is defined like that in RFC 1034:

> Additional
> Carries RRs which may be helpful in using the RRs in the
> other sections.

It then comes fully in §4.3.2 that describes the resolution algorithm:

> Copy the NS RRs for the subzone into the authority
> section of the reply.  Put whatever addresses are
> available into the additional section, using glue RRs
> if the addresses are not available from authoritative
> data or the cache.  Go to step 4.

Back to RFC 8499 you do get further explanations:

> A response that has only a referral contains an empty answer
> section.  It contains the NS RRset for the referred-to zone in the
> Authority section.  It may contain RRs that provide addresses in
> the additional section.  The AA bit is clear.

and

> In the case where the query matches an alias, and the server is
> not authoritative for the target of the alias but is authoritative
> for some name above the target of the alias, the resolution
> algorithm will produce a response that contains both the
> authoritative answer for the alias and a referral.  Such a partial
> answer and referral response has data in the Answer section.  It
> has the NS RRset for the referred-to zone in the Authority
> section.  It may contain RRs that provide addresses in the
> additional section.

As for:

> However, I have seen some implementation

Yes, the content of `ADDITIONAL` might change depending on which nameserver you query and how it is configured. See for example the `minimal-responses` option of Bind, documented at https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html stating: "This option controls the addition of records to the authority and additional sections of responses. Such records may be included in responses to be helpful to clients; for example, NS or MX records may have associated address records included in the additional section, obviating the need for a separate address lookup. However, adding these records to responses is not mandatory and requires additional database lookups, causing extra latency when marshalling responses." It has 4 possible values so many different behaviors online.

And finally for:

> since the TLD server manages the net. zone, we can believe anything under net.

Yes, and no :-). Take for example the Verisign SiteFinder "experiment" in the past: you query any com authoritative nameservers for any non existing name and you got back an `A` record. Do you believe it or not?

Comment: When you say "except when there is no other way to achieve something, which are glues", basic use case I guess is for TLD server since there is no other way to get the IPs without having a loop. But in this case, since both refer each other, is it excepted to use the ADDITIONAL section since there is no other way? I do not see another way to resolve the domain without using glue records

Comment: Yes, ADDITIONAL is exactly because of the need of glues, they can't be anywhere else. But in the past ADDITIONAL was also used for other stuff, like if you query for `MX` you get an hostname back (and a preference), and a nameserver could also put the A/AAAA records for that hostname directly in the ADDITIONAL section of the response having the `MX` record in the ANSWER section, as an optimization to avoid one turnaround... except that this data (in ADDITIONAL) might not be authoritative.